# How we can count foreach loop fields from DB?

Tags: laravel

This is `News` model

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;

use Brexis\LaravelWorkflow\Traits\WorkflowTrait;
//use Hyn\Tenancy\Abstracts\TenantModel as TenancyModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class News extends Model {
    use WorkflowTrait;

    protected $table = 'news_info';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'header', 'description', 'status', 'created_by', 'media_url', 'media_thumbnail',
    ];
```

Inside `Status` field we store values like `validated` and `pre_validation`.

This is my method which is giving all fields in array.

```
public function newsStatusCount(Request $request){
        $status=News::all('status');
    return $status;


    }
```

I am getting this output

```
[
    {
        "status": "pre_validation"
    },
    {
        "status": "pre_validation"
    },
    {
        "status": "validated"
    },
    {
        "status": "pre_validation"
    },
    {
        "status": "pre_validation"
    },
    {
        "status": "pre_validation"
    },
    {
        "status": "pre_validation"
    },
    {
        "status": "pre_validation"
    },
    {
        "status": "pre_validation"
    },
    {
        "status": "pre_validation"
    },
]
```

if I use `count()` function to $status, it gives number of status.
I want to count the number of news with status `pre_validation` and `validated`.
Can any one help me regarding this.
Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: check my answer. It solve your problem and best way to do.

Answer (score 1):

To check how many News have those statuses, use multiple `where` clauses

```
$status = News::where('status', 'pre_validation')->orWhere('status', 'validated')->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $status=News::select('status', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('status')
             ->get();
```

Try my answer it will solve your problem.

Comment: It worked. But can you please do it without using raw.

Comment: why? it's the best way. Accept my answer it solve your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely it worked for me. Is it possible to do it without raw?

Comment: I am not sure. check doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions . It's best practice.